# How to render a big dynamic list view with react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a CMS page which might includes goods or images floors. The images might not have a certain ratio or size.
And the product component should support adding to cart.

I'm using `FlatList` to render these data. But it seems like it's not a good choice cause the rendering processes quite slow and it looks like main thread will be blocked during the first rendering. And when scrolling quickly, there will be some empty blocks.

After reading the document of `recyclerlistview` from Flipkart, it seems like it's not a good choice for encouraging a certain layout size of each row, while images of my floors does not have.

Is there any suggestion to render such a CMS page with RN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Shahen Hovhannisyan's answer is good suggestion.
But considering `react-native-largelist` has a lower rate and star. I did not import it in our project.

My solution is keeping use of react-native's `FlatList`. And wrapping items with `React.memo` or using `PureComponent` instead of `Component` to avoid wasted renderings. I also gave a certain layout for images. In my experience, this will increase `FlatList`'s rendering experience. Replacing `Image` with `react-native-fast-image` is also an effective improvement. This will cause a lower memory usage and a better cache. BTW, for `react-native` 0.59, use `react-native-fast-image` 6.1.1 for the latest version only support RN 0.60+.

Answer (score 0):

**FlatList** itself is a **Slow** component. It has huge gain from a memory perspective but performs slow.

Try to use https://github.com/bolan9999/react-native-largelist package for large lists, This seems to perform better for me.

Comment: Agree with u about `FlatList`. 

It seems like `react-native-largelist` is a good choice. But considering about the stars and used-by, I doubt is it good to use it in production env. 

Are you using this lib in production? And is there any problem in your product with this lib?